# Symfony 3 and Docker (nginx, php7.1-fpm mysql8) Performances low on Windows

Tags: nginx, docker, symfony, php-7, mysql-8.0

I'm using Docker to work on Symfony 3 project, Here is the following stack :

-Custom **Php7.1FPM** here's the DockerFile :

```
FROM php:7.1.0-fpm
MAINTAINER xxxxx xxxxxx <xxxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com>
ENV PHP_APCU_VERSION 5.1.8
ENV PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION 2.5.0
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libicu-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && curl -L -o /tmp/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz https://pecl.php.net/get/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz \
    && curl -L -o /tmp/xdebug-$PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION.tgz http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-$PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION.tgz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/xdebug-$PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION.tgz \
    && rm -r \
        /tmp/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz \
        /tmp/xdebug-$PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION.tgz \
    && mv apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/apcu \
    && mv xdebug-$PHP_XDEBUG_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        apcu \
        intl \
        mbstring \
        mysqli \
        xdebug \
        zip \
    && pecl install apcu_bc-1.0.3 \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

- last **nginx** image
- **mysql**:8.0.0

I use docker-compose to build those 3 containers, here's the docker-compose.yml :

```
front:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - "81:80"
    links:
        - "engine:engine"
    volumes:
        - ".:/home/docker:ro"
        - "./docker/front/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"
engine:
    build: ./docker/engine/
    volumes:
        - ".:/home/docker:rw"
        - "./docker/engine/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini:ro"
    links:
        - "db:db"
    working_dir: "/home/docker"

db:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd
        - MYSQL_USER=myUSer
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=bddProject
```

The first time without cache the time is 1700 ms :

[image]

And the time with cache is :

[image]

The half time is initialisation time :

So What kind of problem could slow the page render of my project ?
Docker last version and 2 Go with Windows Hyper-v system.

Thank you for your help.

---

So i make an other image without xdebug ant the result is the same 
(700ms with cache) :

My DockerFile :

```
FROM php:7.1.0-fpm
MAINTAINER XXXXX XXXXXX <XXXXXX.XXXXXX@gmail.com>
ENV PHP_APCU_VERSION 5.1.8
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        libicu-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
    && docker-php-source extract \
    && curl -L -o /tmp/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz https://pecl.php.net/get/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz \
    && rm -r \
        /tmp/apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION.tgz \
    && mv apcu-$PHP_APCU_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        apcu \
        intl \
        mbstring \
        mysqli \
        zip \
    && pecl install apcu_bc-1.0.3 \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

So it's the window's management of Docker volume which make that, so @Geoffrey Brier you know if Microsoft has planned to improve this performance problem ? 
Is there a soft or other to improve that ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there are two things that are responsible for those performances :

- Xdebug
- Windows : it's no troll but it's a well known problem that the way your containers volumes are handled by Docker on Windows is not as efficient as on Linux.

You have three solutions : struggle to find a method that slightly improves the performances, use Linux (in a VM for instance) or deal with it :)

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try with fpm without xdebug to see if there is performance's improvements. It's not awful 650 ms but i just want to known if this is normal.In production my server will be on linux so it's not realy a problem ...

Comment: I confirm that it's normal. And also when the latency is < 2 seconds it's clearly correct to develop ;) Btw your machine must be quite good to have those kind of results because some of my friends had to wait like 5~10 seconds for pages to be displayed on their windows.